# Store Min, Max,Avg values in "single" variable

Tags: c#

I have many variable like:

```
int signalX_Max;
int signalX_Min;
int signalX_Avg;
int signalY_Max;
int signalY_Min;
int signalY_Avg;
int signalZ_Min;
int signalZ_Max;
int signalZ_Avg;
```

How can I store/declare this variables to to use it in code like `signal.yMin, signal.yMax, signal.yAvg, signal.xMin, signal.xMax, signal.xAvg` etc. or `signal['xMin'], signal['xMax'],signal['xAvg']` etc

Comment: Create a class?

Comment: Create a struct?

Comment: Please only use the [visual-studio] tag for questions about the tool itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a class and then have the above as properties. Then create an instance of it. You could access with the dot operator

```
 public class Signal
        {
            int signalX_Max  { get; set; }
            int signalX_Min { get; set; }
            int signalX_Avg { get; set; }
            int signalY_Max { get; set; }
            int signalY_Min { get; set; }
            int signalY_Avg { get; set; }
            int signalZ_Min { get; set; }
            int signalZ_Max { get; set; }
            int signalZ_Avg { get; set; }

        }
```

Then you could do ,

```
   Signal signal = new Signal();
   signal.signalX_Avg = ....
```

Comment: It's doesn't work :/ when I try `signal.` then I have only options `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, `GetType`, `ToString` no options for `signalX_Avg` and others

Comment: Did you create an instance of that class

Comment: yes, `Signal signal = new Signal();`

Comment: I find it. It should be `public int signalX_Max  { get; set; }` rather than `int signalX_Max  { get; set; }` inside class declaration